# What is the proper way to launch project from repo on local?

Tags: git, symfony

I was reading tutorials about setting up project from repo in Symfony (3.3.10) and I did this kind of process:

1. Install symfony.
2. command "php symfony new project-name 3.3.10"
3. git clone project-url
4. Copy manually symfony and project files to project directory
5. git init in project directory
6. installing the vendors

What's in repo? In repo I have:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgwn78zervsdzrz/2017-12-19_20h36_24.jpg?dl=0
And this is gitignore:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mh0ezucv1r1odyr/2017-12-19_20h36_38.jpg?dl=0

As can you see I don't keep vendors in repo so every developer has to install it manually. I'm not sure why but in every tutorial was information that it's good way.

My questions are:

1. Is this process right or can I do it better?
2. How to make simpler point 6? Installing all vendors manually is not easy and fast. And of course I have to inform everybody what vendors project is using.

Thanks.
Lukasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup.html#installing-an-existing-symfony-application), and assuming git and composer are installed on your local machine, you only need steps 3 (git clone) and 6 (install vendors).

To install all vendors in one command, you just have to run `composer install`, there is no need to install all vendors manually.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure... For example I used bundle https://github.com/avanzu/AdminThemeBundle and there are few additional commands to do manually, e.g.:
php bin/console avanzu:admin:initialize
php bin/console assets:install --symlink
php bin/console avanzu:admin:fetch-vendor
without those bundle doesn't work properly.

Comment: Well, I would say you can create a batch file with all the commands you need to execute. Then you would need step 3 (git clone), step 6 (composer install) and step 7 (execute the batch file).

Comment: You mean simple .bat file with commands which I need for vendors to install them?

Answer (score 1):

**How to make simple install dependencies?**

Commit composer.lock and automate the provision of the server.

**Can you do it better?**

You can do it different, if it is better it depends on your needs.

The basic symfony setup is quite easy to install but overtime it gets more and more complicated. So you can automate that for the development environment and deployment to production.

Average symfony setup tasks:

- Install dependencies (composer, npm, bower)
- Build frontend (Angular, React, etc)
- Run doctrine migrations
- Flush redis/memcached/apc
- Restart php-fpm / apache
- Import fixtues

**Development environtment**

You want that your environment it is as closer as the server you will run it.

- vagrant
- ansible http://phansible.com/

**Deploying to production**

- PHP Deployer https://deployer.org/
- Capistrano http://capistranorb.com/
- AWS Elasticbeanstalk?

If your project gets even more complicated you can have a build project that creates a zipfile/phar/docker image with everything you need and deploy the build to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a repo on Git you do not need to `command "php symfony new project-name 3.3.10"` because it is create a empty project. Then, if you want have vendors, you should install project dependencies;

`composer install`into project directory.

And, remove lines into `.gitignore`

```
1-) /bin/*
2-) /var/*
3-) /web/*
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that most of tutorials tells that there is no reason to keep in repo /bin/ /var/ /web/ files... Or I don't understand something?